# Could you please recommend AMC 8 preparation book?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, contest-math, book-recommendation

Could you please recommend **AMC 8 preparation book**?
Friend of mine recommended **AMC 8 preparation book (by Sedrakyan)**, he told it is a great book with great (new) practice tests and must-know theory. He told it is the best book for AMC 8 preparation. Any other suggestions?
I need AMC 8, AMC 10, AMC 12 and AIME books (both for me and for my brother).

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer:  this is not a specific endorsement of any particular author or publisher; please feel free to consider other alternatives.

The first place I would look is official past exam material.  These are available for purchase through the [MAA's website](https://www.maa.org/math-competitions/amc-preparation-materials-for-purchase).  The advantage here is clear:  you get official problems presented in a structure that already models the exam, so you can work on test-taking strategy such as pacing and checking your work.

Next, I would also consider reputable sources for contest problem solving, such as the Art of Problem Solving.  They offer three textbooks suited to your purposes:  [AoPS Volume 1](https://artofproblemsolving.com/store/book/aops-vol1), Volume 2, and Competition Math for Middle School.

Finally, I would consider enrolling in a training program rather than just independent study.  This enforces structure in a way that even the most self-motivated students often cannot achieve on their own.  Working with an instructor in a class environment also encourages collaboration, provides more immediate feedback, and exposes students to ways of thinking mathematically that they might not have seen before.

Answer (score 0):

For problems:  you can look at CEMC Canada contest problems, UKMT contest problems.  If you want to get to top 1-2% of students, a lot of work has to be done. Contest Problems Books from MAA can be used. you can also use MathCount past contest problems

Answer (score 0):

Sedrakyan actually has AMC 12 and AIME preparation books also. Both are insanely helpful and cover different theories, with new practice tests. That’s insane how many new formulas and super useful results are included in both books (especially in the AIME preparation book). If I am not mistaken this year Sedrakyans received Erdös award for their contributions to mathematics.